# Number of possible configurations by shifting the '2's in $12121212$ to the right.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I came up with this question while solving another combinatorics problem.

> Let's say there is a number $12121212$. Define an operation as swapping any two adjacent digits if the left digit is $2$. (For example, swapping the $2$<sup>$nd$</sup> and $3$<sup>$rd$</sup> digit to give $11221212$ as a result, but swapping the $3$<sup>$rd$</sup> and $4$<sup>$th$</sup> digit is not allowed.) There is no limit on how many operations you can do on the number(no operation is also possible). How many possible numbers can be formed?

### Questions

- Is there a name to this kind of problems?
- How can it be solved?
- Extra: What if the original is not $12121212$ but some other numbers(like for example$121212121111111111$? Will this make the question very complicated?

### My attempt

I am not sure how to approach this question. My observation is that the final configuration $11112222$ remains unchanged after any operations. So it seems that the first '$2$' originally at $2$<sup>$nd$</sup> position moves to the $5$<sup>$th$</sup>  position, the first '$2$' orginally at $4$<sup>$th$</sup> position moves to the $6$<sup>$th$</sup> position and so on.
However, some of the cases are invalid but at least I know that number of possible configurations is less than $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1 = 24$. So a possible way will be to enumerate all possible configurations, but it is a pain because I cannot find a way to do it in an organised manner. Therefore, I am curious if there is a way to do it more efficiently and smartly.

Comment: Count the number of $1$'s to the right of each $2$ and associate such a sequence of results with a tuple.  In your example of `12121212` this would be $(3,2,1,0)$.  Convince yourself that any tuple corresponds to an arrangement and vice versa.  Further convince yourself that the tuple is weakly decreasing (*weakly in the sense each number is greater or equal to the next number in the tuple, not necessarily strictly greater*) and that every weakly decreasing tuple whose entries are all less than or equal to their corresponding entries in the original tuple correspond to possible final outcomes.

Comment: This all suggests an easy way to organize your thoughts for a brute force approach, listing things in numerical order... here: 3210, 3200, 3110, 3100, 3000, 2210, ... ,0000 yielding precisely $14$ different outcomes, corresponding to 12121212, 12121122, 12112212, ... 11112222 respectively for your original problem.  As for coming up with a formula to count the number of weakly decreasing sequences $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_k)$ subject to $a_i\leq b_i$ for each $i$ for some given initial configuration $(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_k)$, I don't see a clever way right away how to do that.

Comment: @JMoravitz Just to make sure that I am understanding it correctly, The answer to the $12121212$ case will be $14$, right?

Comment: Not sure whether this is helpful. But for the $12121212$ case, the problem has another representation:
Find a number of 8-digit numbers satisfying the following 2 condition: 1.The digits of the integer consist of exaclty 4 copies of '1' and 4 copies of '2'. 
2.if we remove the last k digits from the integer(where k is any positive integer less than 8), the resulting integer has at least many '1's as '2's

Comment: Isn't this the Catalan number? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: @Naruki do you mean the $12121212$ case or the generalised version?

Comment: I mean 12121212 (or more generally 12 repeated) case, but I think the proof https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Second_proof can be used for 121212121111111111 (but not a random one).

Comment: @Naruki I agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of these strings as describing mountain paths from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle 2n,0\rangle$, where $n$ is the number of $1$s (or $2$s): each $1$ corresponds to an up-step from $\langle x,y\rangle$ to $\langle x+1,y+1\rangle$, and each $2$ to a down-step from $\langle x,y\rangle$ to $\langle x+1,y-1\rangle$. Initially we have a path that looks like this:

```
             /\/\/\/\.../\
```

Each legal move consists in interchanging a down-step with the step to its immediate right. If that step is also a down-step, the path doesn’t change. Otherwise a sequence `\/` is converted to a sequence `/\`. We still have $n$ up-steps and $n$ down-steps, so the path still ends at $\langle 2n,0\rangle$, and an easy induction shows that no path obtainable in this way drops below the $x$-axis.

It takes a bit more work to show that **every** mountain path from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle 2n,0\rangle$ that never drops below the $x$-axis is obtainable in this way, but once we have that, we’re done: it’s well-known that the number of such paths is $C_n$, the $n$-th Catalan number.

The idea is simple enough. Take any such mountain path $P$. Reading from left to right, find the first peak at a height greater than $1$. (If there isn’t one, we’re done: it’s our initial path.) That peak consists of an up-step followed by a down-step; interchange those two steps. This interchange is simply the inverse of the legal move in the original procedure. Repeat this process until there are no more peaks of height greater than $1$. At that point you have the path

```
             /\/\/\/\.../\,
```

and $P$ can clearly be obtained from it by a sequence of legal moves.

Comment: I marked this as accepted. However, what if the string is more random, say $2211212212$? Is enumerating the only possible way?

Comment: @LearningMathematics: For a given starting string? Probably, though if the initial string is restricted to some fairly narrowly defined class of forms, it might be possible to come up with a closed form for the number of possible derived strings.

Comment: is there a way to prove that there is no closed form for the general case?